# Search a file in 4 different path using powershell

Tags: search, powershell

I need to search in 4 different path:

```
C:\Program Files\test1
C:\Program Files\test3
C:\Program Files (x86)\test6
D:\
```

I am using the following shell command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter file.txt -Recurse  | fl directory > C:\filereport.txt
```

Can you please help me to use a similar command that would search all the above path and also not cut the path?

In fact, when I extract the file some path are cut. I would need the length to be longer as after **107** characters it is not showed in **1** line

Thanks,
Graig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$p = "C:\Program Files\test1", "C:\Program Files\test3", "C:\Program Files (x86)\test6", "D:\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $p -Filter file.txt -Recurse | select directory | ac C:\filereport.txt
```